# How to trigger UpdateProgress on initial pageload in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

**Question:**
Why does my UpdateProgress not show during the initial page load but does for subsequent postbacks via button click?

The only way I have managed to get this working is with a timer, which I'm not keen on. Is there another way?

Can someone explain why `doSearch()` causes the updateprogress to work from a button click but not on pageload via docoment ready?

**Code:**

Js handler:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(doSearch);

    function doSearch() {
        $('#<%= UpdatePanel1Trigger.ClientID %>').click();
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

aspx:

```
//if i click this button the updateprogress works
//and the panel loads
<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" CssClass="form-control"  
 OnClientClick="return doSearch();"  />

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional"
    OnLoad="UpdatePanel1_Load" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="UpdatePanel1Trigger" runat="server" 
               style="display:none" OnClick="UpdatePanel1Trigger_Click" />
        <%--gridview that takes a while to load--%>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" 
    AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1" DisplayAfter="1">
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="imgUpdateProgress1" runat="server" 
        ImageUrl="~/Images/spinner.gif" AlternateText="Loading ..." ToolTip="Loading ..."/>
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```

Codebehind:

```
    protected void UpdatePanel1Trigger_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(m_search))
        {
            performSearch(); //loads data for gridview in updatepanel
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

At last I think I found it:

```
<%@Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false"
         CodeFile="prueba.aspx.vb" Inherits="Programación_prueba" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
  <title>UpdatePanel Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true"/>
  <asp:UpdateProgress runat="server" ID="PageUpdateProgress">
    <ProgressTemplate>
      Loading...
    </ProgressTemplate>
  </asp:UpdateProgress>
  <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="Panel">
    <ContentTemplate>
      <asp:Button runat="server" ID="UpdateButton" OnClick="UpdateButton_Click" Text="Update"/>
      <asp:Timer runat="server" ID="UpdateTimer" Interval="5000" OnTick="UpdateTimer_Tick"/>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger controlid="UpdateTimer" eventname="Tick"/>
    </Triggers>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code behind:

```
Partial Class Programación_prueba
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub UpdateButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles UpdateButton.Click
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
    End Sub

    Protected Sub UpdateTimer_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles UpdateTimer.Tick
        Me.UpdateButton_Click(Me.UpdateButton, Nothing)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Many thanks for all the ideas.
Aurelio J. Maldonado

Comment: Could you please explain what you changed (and why)?

Answer (score 0):

Could be something in a way jQuery library interferes with MS AJAX library. Try to force it to show:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#<%= UpdateProgress1.ClientID %>').show();    
         doSearch();
    });

    function doSearch() {
        $('#<%= UpdatePanel1Trigger.ClientID %>').click();
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

As an alternative instead jQuery's `$(document).ready` try using MS approach:

```
<script>
    Sys.Application.add_load(doSearch);

    function doSearch() {
        $('#<%= UpdatePanel1Trigger.ClientID %>').click();
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: THanks for your reply, the first method was the same as my current (except it showed the button until the panel loaded). The second didn't load anything at all (didn't click the button).